# SQL Select count 2 columns and inverted values

Tags: sql, select, count

I have this query to list and count different resolutions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w, h, count(*) as c from resolution GROUP BY w, h
```

Now I'd like the same while grouping the values where (w, h) == (h, w), to count 1200 x 800 in the same line as 800 x 1200 for example.

A single SQL statement would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
select (case when w < h then w else h end) as v1,
       (case when w < h then h else w end) as v2,
       count(*) as c
from resolution r
group by (case when w < h then w else h end),
         (case when w < h then h else w end);
```

Note that you almost never need `distinct` when using `group by`.

Also, some databases have `least()` and `greatest()` functions that can simplify the code, but you do not specify what database you are using.  The above is ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: Great! It works perfectly. Didn't know about these conditions and "end" code. Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm using MySql, so this would be the equivalent of SELECT GREATEST (w, h), LEAST (w, h), count(*) as c from resolution GROUP BY w, h Thanks again for your teaching !

Comment: @S.E. . . . These are equivalent if neither `w` and `h` are ever `NULL`.